# kubuntu for usb, where to find this iso-file?

Tags: kubuntu, usb-drive, iso

I downloaded Universal-USB-Installer-1.8.9.6 to install kubuntu at an usb-drive. Now the installer is asking for an iso-file. where can I find it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to download kubuntu iso from the internet(or if you have the cd, just insert it)

> Universal USB Installer is a Live Linux USB Creator that allows you to
>   choose from a selection of Linux Distributions to put on your USB
>   Flash Drive

more info [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

You can download Kubuntu.iso from [here](http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/download)

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find the ISO - http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/download